# Implementing a "configurable" joining system, safely

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

**Background**

Hello, I'm developing an experimental/educational tool in PHP and MySQL.  I'm new to SQL, but I want to do things the right way from the start.  I'm using PDO prepared statements for all variable substitutions, and backticking everywhere possible (thus, as I understand, it won't be portable to non-MySQL databases).  Regarding my problem, I have an idea as to how to go forth, but it's going to take me several hours to implement (I'm new even to the syntax of SQL), so meanwhile I thought I'd create a question first just in case someone can yell, "This is not the way to do it!" and save me hours of effort.

**Problem**

I would like to create an interface where a user would select from dropdown menus:

1. a table `A`,
2. one or more fields on that table, e.g. `A.x` and `A.y`,
3. a table `B`,
4. one or more fields on that table, e.g. `B.z` and `B.y`,

and upon submission the code would perform an inner join, matching each field respectively, e.g. `A.x = B.z`, `A.y = B.y`, etc. and return all matched rows.

My plan is simply to generate an `INNER JOIN` SQL statement, looping through the fields and inserting placeholders (`?`), binding the respective parameters, and finally executing the statement.

Is there an easier way of doing this?  Is there a better way of doing this?  Will this be somehow exploitable?

Thank you very much, in advance.  If no one responds by the time I finish (doubtful), I will post my solution.

**Misc.**

Assume that I will validate

1. that the user selects an equal number of fields between `A` and `B`,
2. that the fields and tables exist,
3. etc.

and that the field names need not be identical: they will be matched in order.  (Do point out any other details I might not be aware of!)

Eventually, the goal is for these selections to be saved in a "settings" table themselves.  In effect, users create "views" they would like to see each time they come back.

Comment: +1 really informative question... way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing so much right that I actually feel guilty pointing out that you're doing something wrong! :)

You can only use prepared statements to parameterise field values—not SQL identifiers such as column or table names.  Therefore you won't be able to pass `A.x`, `B.z` etc. into your `JOIN` criteria by way of prepared statement parameters: you *must* instead do what feels terribly wrong and directly concatenate them into your SQL string.

However, all is not lost.  In some vague order of preference, you can:

1. Present the user with an option list, from which you subsequently reassemble the SQL:

   ```
   <select name="join_a">
     <option value="1">x</option>
     <option value="2">y</option>
   </select>
   <select name="join_b">
     <option value="1">z</option>
     <option value="2">y</option>
   </select>
   ```

   Then your form handler:

   ```
   switch ($_POST['join_a']) {
     case 1:  $acol = 'x'; break;
     case 2:  $acol = 'y'; break;
     default: die('Invalid input');
   }
   switch ($_POST['join_b']) {
     case 1:  $bcol = 'z'; break;
     case 2:  $bcol = 'y'; break;
     default: die('Invalid input');
   }

   $sql .= "FROM A JOIN B ON A.$acol = B.$bcol";
   ```

   This approach has the advantage that, short of compromising PHP (in which case you'll have far bigger concerns than SQL injection), arbitrary SQL absolutely *cannot* find its way into your RDBMS.
2. Ensure the user input matches one of the expected values:

   ```
   <select name="join_a">
     <option>x</option>
     <option>y</option>
   </select>
   <select name="join_b">
     <option>z</option>
     <option>y</option>
   </select>
   ```

   Then your form handler:

   ```
   if (!in_array($_POST['join_a'], ['x', 'y'])
    or !in_array($_POST['join_b'], ['z', 'y']))
      die('Invalid input');

   $sql .= "FROM A JOIN B ON A.$_POST[join_a] = B.$_POST[join_b]";
   ```

   This approach relies on PHP's `in_array` function for safety (and also exposes to the user your underlying column names, but given your application I doubt that's a concern).
3. Perform some input cleansing, such as:

   ```
   mb_regex_encoding($charset); // charset of database connection
   $sql .= 'FROM A JOIN B ON A.`' . mb_ereg_replace('`', '``', $_POST['join_a']) . '`'
                       . ' = B.`' . mb_ereg_replace('`', '``', $_POST['join_b']) . '`'
   ```

   Whilst we here quote the user input and replace any attempt by the user to escape from that quoting, this approach could be full of all sorts of flaws and vulnerabilities (in either PHP's `mb_ereg_replace` function or MySQL's handling of specially crafted strings within a quoted identifier).

   It is *far* better if at all possible to use one of the above methods to avoid inserting user-defined strings into one's SQL altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that user input is limited to only selecting the tables and fields (i.e. no additional conditions), you should be fine with your approach; sounds interesting :)

One thing I would like to add is that certain joins are better than others. For example, joining two tables using their primary keys (or other indexes) will perform way better than two unrelated columns for which a full table scan is required.

This all depends on how big the tables are in the first place; for less than a few thousand records, you should be okay; anything beyond serious contemplation is in place :)

Comment: @eggyal ah, there's that too :) well spotted!

Comment: Thanks; this seems partly a compact version of the answer I accepted--sorry I had to give it to the other guy/gal.  Yes, it looks like I'll have to display and check table and field names. Good point about the efficiency of joins.  As this is partly an educational tool, I'd actually like to leave that detail up to the user to manage, but I'll definitely create a caption that explains the importance of primary keys and indexes (indices?).